# Telegram Bot: How to delete/remove userpic of bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to remove the user picture of my telegram bot but there seems to be no option. Is it possible to delete/remove the userpic of a bot?

I know that I could upload any other photo via botfathers `/setuserpic` command but I want to simply remove the pic without any replacement.

Comment: Why don't just put an blank photo?

Comment: @Sean, that would be possible but as I wrote I want to delete and not replace it. Uploading a blank image feels like a workaround. :)
But it seems that no other option for this is available at the moment.

Comment: Currently it seems that the botfather adds the new pic and the old pic also remains. When clicking on the bot image both pictures can be seen as a slider-gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open BotFather
- /mybots
- Select your bot
- Click Edit
- Click Edit Botpic
- Send a new picture to Bot Father

Bot father will add the latest photo as Display Picture.

**Note:** Bot father does remove the old picture. After changing the profile picture... open your bot... and check dp from there... you'll see only the last updated one.
Remember, if you check dp from the chat list(or Rows) you'll see earlier picture too. But that too gets removed once you open your bot and check dp from chat window!

Answer (score 3):

Currently there seems to be no way to remove the pic completely.

Comment: Wrong! Changes holds until restarting telegram! So change userpic and restart telegram